# jQuery auto update browser issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-11, record

I'm using this piece of code to delete a record, but after a successful deletion the record still appear on my browser until I refresh the screen. Assuming the record supposed to dissappear once I confirm "OK" on my warning popup. Anybody have an idea what's the issue? Thanks!

$( '.removeREC' ).bind( 'click', function( e ) {
        if (confirm('This will delete the attachment.  Are you sure you wish to continue?')) {
          $( "div##comments" ).hide();
          var recID = $( this ).attr( 'data-recid' );

```
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/SWS/Components/inc_post_running_standards.cfc?method=mark&as=D&id=" + recID,
        success: function( response ) {
          //$(##RecDetails).html( response );
        }
      });
    }
  });
```